# Could not find io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I want to install Firebase Crashlytics on my project but I encounter such a problem when building

Tried
- I can do comment //apply plugin: "io.fabric"
- I Dropped the version classpath `'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'` to `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'`

android/build.gradle

```
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
```

```
  maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class io.invertase.firebase.** { *; }
-dontwarn io.invertase.firebase.**
```

app/build.gradle

```
    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }


apply plugin: "io.fabric"
```

Problem

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.28.1/gradle-1.28.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.28.1/gradle-1.28.1.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.28.1/gradle-1.28.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.28.1/gradle-1.28.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

project.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

    }
```

app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add following code into app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
..........
 }
```